# Adjust size of JDatePicker Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm using `JDatePicker` from http://jdatepicker.org. It's cool but i cannot find any ways to change the size of the text box and the button. the `setSize()` only change size of the container as picture below. Any suggestions please?

[image]

Update: I've figured out a way that is using JFormattedTextField to point the instance of the datepicker 's textfield and resize it. The code as below:

```
UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("text.today", "Today");
    p.put("text.month", "Month");
    p.put("text.year", "Year");
    JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
    JDatePickerImpl dpDoB = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, af);
    dpDoB.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(195, 45));
    JFormattedTextField tf = dpDoB.getJFormattedTextField();
    tf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(195, 35));
    Font font = new Font("Tahoma", 0, 16);
    tf.setFont(font);
    dpDoB.setShowYearButtons(false);
    dpDoB.setTextEditable(true);
    panelDoB.add(dpDoB);
```

There is still the button left unable to resize. So i'm not sure if there are any other ways to solve this

Comment: It comes with source code, so you can see how it's constructed. But more importantly, you're not showing your own code, how you're trying to use it, and most importantly, **what layout manager you're using**. If you're just using FlowLayout, then nothing will resize. Have you tried BoxLayout or one of the other managers?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've figured out a way which is by using JFormattedTextField to point the instance of the text box, then resize it. Though there is still a button left being unable to access.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for componet of JDatePickerImpl (this class have only two)

Try this:

```
UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("text.today", "Today");
    p.put("text.month", "Month");
    p.put("text.year", "Year");
    JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
    datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new DateLabelFormatter());
    datePicker.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,20));
    datePicker.getComponent(0).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20)); //JFormattedTextField
    datePicker.getComponent(1).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));//JButton
    add(datePicker);
```

Comment: HI, ty for your contribution. I've managed to solve this case.